# How to mount a ext2 partition in sdcard

Tags: sd-card, shell, mount, ext2

I don't want to use fat32, I want use the more stable ext2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use anything but FAT for the external SDCard. Android will not mount the card if it is not FAT.

Comment: And the internal memory what uses, that depends on the ROM?

Comment: Internal SDCard? I believe that is also FAT. as for the other areas of the internal storage, like /system and such is ext4 starting with 2.3. Prior to that it used yaffs2.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do it on Harmony developer board using adb shell:

```
adb shell "mount -t ext2 /dev/block/mmcblk3p1 /mnt/sdcard"
```